# Angular2 Two-Way Data Binding not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Here is an example code:

```
var SampleComponent7 = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "sampleseven",
    template: "<input [(value)]='name' /><input (click)='clicked()' value='Click here' type='submit' />"
}).Class({
    constructor: function(){
        this.name = "";
    },
    clicked: function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
})
```

The alert box seems to always print empty string even if I enter some value in the input box. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following with `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]`:

```
var SampleComponent7 = ng.core.Component({
  selector: 'sampleseven',
  template: '<input [(ngModel)]="name" /><input (click)="clicked()" value="Click here" type="submit" />'
}).Class({
  constructor: function(){
    this.name = "";
  },
  clicked: function(){
    alert(this.name);
  }
});
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PevjoFUasncybPGnVkU0?p=preview.

Comment: You need to use `ngModel` instead... I updated my answer.

Comment: It works if I use angular2-all.umd.dev.js but not when I use angular2-all.umd.min.js. Any reason why?

Comment: I know that there are some issues regarding minification in Angular2. Which version do you use?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4