# Accordion is not opening after binding data from API in Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

Working in an Angular 4 application ,In this I have accordion inside accordion,Now I am trying to bind the accordion dynamically from API response (json).

Here in my case the accordion header is binding but not the inner options are not getting bind .

**I can't say exactly whether it's binding but not open or it is not get bind.**

Working Example with static values:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9cuvb9?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Dynamic binding :(with Issue)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-jwb2zj?file=app/app.component.html

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully aware of the exact goal you try to achieve, but in dynamic version you set data target - `href="#collapseInnerTwo"` and in `id` of collapsable you try to evaluate some expression - `[id]="'collapseInnerTwo' + group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC"`

These will never match and never collapse. If you change

`[id]="'collapseInnerTwo' + group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC"`

To

`id="collapseInnerTwo"`

[It works as supposed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-4o6mbh?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: in api there are 4 group but here it binding only one group,Please take a look at the working demo of you